# jQuery $(document).on() does not work for HTML5 video tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I want my HTML5 video (`<video>` tag) to play / pause on click. With this code, it works perfectly :

```
$("video").on("click", function () {
    var video = $(this).get(0);

    if (video.paused === false) {
        video.pause();
    } else {
        video.play();
    }
});
```

However, I'm appending some new `<video>` tags in the DOM so I thought that implenting this code would do what I need :

```
$(document).on("click", "video", function () {
    var video = $(this).get(0);

    if (video.paused === false) {
        video.pause();
    } else {
        video.play();
    }
});
```

But with `$(document).on()` the clicks on my video elements are not detected anymore... Is there any reason to that ?

Comment: Looks like the video play is stopping propagation of the clicks. Looks for `video` specific events instead (if your player triggers any).

Comment: @mplungjan: Delegated events on `document` do not need a DOM ready wrapper as `document` always exists

Comment: apply class "pausablevideo" or something like that, and use the class as selector..

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am trying this in a WKWebview in iOs. Seems like everything is working as expected in the desktop browser. Maybe it's a WKWebview related issue then...